# matlab nchoosek limitation workaround

Tags: matlab, permutation, combinations

I would like to use matlab to create a matrix full of all possible combinations of size 8 in the dataset V= 0:46. This does not seem to be possible using nchoosek. Could someone help me with a workaround? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to create a matrix of 314457495-by-8 elements you can create your own function. A recursive solution would be

```
function R = nck(v, k)
if k==1,
    R = v(:);
elseif k==numel(v),
    R = v(:)';
else
    R0 = nck(v(1:end-1),k);
    R1 = nck(v(1:end-1),k-1);
    R = [R0; R1, v(end)*ones(size(R1,1),1)];
end
R = sortrows(R);
end
```