# Generating all combinations (not all permutations) of n characters with length up to n

Tags: algorithm, matlab, loops, if-statement, combinations

How can we generate all the possible combinations of n characters with length 1 to n in an increasing order of length?

For Example : if n = 4 and characters are 1,2,3,4 
we need to generate an array

```
1,2,3,4
12,13,14,23,24,34
123, 124, 134, 234
1234
```

Here n is the variable and user can feed the n characters.

Comment: You can always use `nchoosek('1234', k)` with a loop on `k`

Comment: Luis , thanks !! it works in matlab but I also needed the algorithm  for coding it in cpp .I am a beginner in matlab so couldn't get enough from the source code in matlab for the function.

Comment: If you need it in C++ that's a different question altogether. I suggest you post it anew with the `C++` tag. Also, people will probably ask what you have tried. You should show your code and where you got stuck or why it doesn't work

Comment: There's a recursive implementation of `nchoosek` in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624776/matlab-nchoosek-limitation-workaround).

Answer (score 0):

There is a bijection between the combinations of up to n elements and the bit masks of length `n`. A way to solve your problem is to generate all bitsets of length n and sort them by the number of bits they have on. You can use [bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) for this.

Create `n+1` lists corresponding to the numbers from 0 to n. Then iterate over all bitmasks and for each bitmask compute the number of bits that are `1` in it and then add the bitmask in the corresponding list. Using those lists it should be pretty easy to solve the problem.